# Getting errors when installing and using sp_blitz with `sqlcmd.exe`?

Tags: sql-server, linux, sp-blitz

I installed this third party thingy, `sp_Blitz`.

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -i ./sp_Blitz.sql
```

But when I run

```
1> EXEC sp_blitz;
2> go
```

I get,

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Procedure sp_blitz, Line 4338
```

> INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: '`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

[image: Error in screen]

## Attempts at the server

When I try to configure `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` I get,

```
1> sp_configure 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER';
2> GO
Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62
The configuration option 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.
```

That's having previously run `sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1; RECONFIGURE;`

## Attempts at the client

### `sqlcmd.exe`

Ok.. So [`sqlcmd.exe`'s docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

> `-I` Sets the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` connection option to `ON`. By default, it is set to `OFF`. For more information, see `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` (Transact-SQL).

However, running with `-I` will show `SESSIONPROPERTY('QUOTED_IDENTIFIER')` as `1` but it doesn't seem to work either

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U Sa -I
Password: 
1> EXEC sp_blitz;
2> GO
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Procedure sp_blitz, Line 4338
INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.
```

### `mssql-cli`

This starts up with `SESSIONPROPERTY('QUOTED_IDENTIFIER')` set to `1` by default, but it generates the same error as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sqlcmd.exe`'s docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

> `-I` Sets the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` connection option to ON. By default, it is set to OFF. For more information, see `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` (Transact-SQL).

The solution running it in sqlcmd (recreate the stored proc with `-I`),

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -I -i ./sp_Blitz.sql
```

Like this,

[image]

You may need to recreate the proc. I would recommend you run it on SSMS because you will get an ugly format result