# What does `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` do, exactly?

Tags: sql-server, linux, configuration

There is a really obnoxious feature in SQL Server called `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` and I wanted to know more about it. In short, with the option set to `ON`, which is not the default with the Linux client, everything works. Without it, some things magically fail. Microsoft claims the option is the `DEFAULT`, and then they default-change it in their own default-client. With `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS OFF;`, this works,

```
CREATE TABLE f (
  a int,
  b int,
  g AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END),
  l AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN b ELSE a END),
  UNIQUE(a,b)
);
```

With `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS OFF;`, this does *not* work,

```
CREATE TABLE f (
  a int,
  b int,
  g AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN a ELSE b END),
  l AS (CASE WHEN a>b THEN b ELSE a END),
  UNIQUE(g,l)
);
```

I just want to know how `g` and `l` are more of an *identifier* than `a` and `b`, and how not supporting this syntax except when enabled by the client was a good or sensible idea? **What exactly is this option doing?**

I only ask because twice now I've been bitten by this,

- [How do I ensure a relationship is commutative and unique?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/195302/2639)
- [Getting errors when installing and using sp_blitz with `sqlcmd.exe`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/193451/2639)

Comment: [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER must be ON when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql)

Comment: Right, what does that have to do with `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS` how does that option name represent what is happening there?

Comment: You might want to look at [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#defaultsettings) from Erland Sommarskog, which contains a table listing the "defaults" of each SQL "Application". Your quote _Microsoft claims the option is the DEFAULT, and then they default-change it in their own default-client_ is stated without a reference, which makes it hard to follow.

Comment: A more useful rant might by why MySQL gives random results without https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Answer (score 5):

An indexed view or index on computed columns is a table index that is related to the table rows by a TSQL expression.  So when mutating the table SQL must determine if the change requires a change also in the indexed view or index on computed column.

To make this easier SQL Server has always required specific SET options be active for the session making the change.  In this case quoted identifiers facilitates determining if the computed columns are affected by the DML statement, as the expression "a" would refer to the column a, and not be a string value.

There's no fundamental reason for this requirement, but normalizing the SET options makes the implementation simpler, and aligns with a broader desire to promote a single, standard set of session settings in applications.

SQLCMD defaults quoted identifiers to off, either for backwards compatibility, compatibility with scripting environments, or perhaps no good reason.

Comment: I wish SQLCMD defaulted to `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`. I know that ship already sailed but it was a great opportunity to introduce a breaking change in the interest of facilitating best practices.